# Python: write unicode value in file

Tags: python, encoding, utf

I'm writing a script that writes files in multiple languages including none ascii text therefore I'm writing the content in unicode.

Here is a print of the data:

```
[['LATEST', u'\u0928\u0935\u0940\u0928\u0924\u092e'], ['RECOMMENDED', u'\u0938\u093f\u092b\u093e\u0930\u093f\u0936 \u0915\u093f\u092f\u093e \u0917\u092f\u093e']]
```

here is the code that I use to write :

```
f = codecs.open(file,encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
f.write(el)
```

This works fine to have to text appear in Hindi in an text editor but because of the file format expected by the server, I need to directly write out

> \u0928\u0935\u0940\u0928\u0924\u092e

I'm currently running

```
os.system("native2ascii -encoding utf-8 ./output/nls_hi.properties ./output/nls_hi.properties")
```

but this takes too much time and I can't help but think that there must be a way to directly write it the right way.

Ideas ?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use something like `my_string.encode('raw_unicode_escape')`

Well, `f = codecs.open('bla.txt', encoding='raw_unicode_escape', mode='w')`

Then the file will contain the escaped string: `\u0928\u0935\u0940\u0928\u0924\u092e`

Comment: that worked, I had looked up the table of encodings but looked at unicode... and didn't think of looking at raw...; still got a long way to go before mastering the documentation !

Comment: You save my lift !!

Answer (score 1):

What file format does the server expect?  Does it need a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) (BOM)?  Whatever the answer, it's easiest to just directly use [`str.encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
data = u'text with Unicode chars etc.'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    # For UTF-8, no BOM:
    f.write(data.encode('utf-8')
```

For UTF-16, use `data.encode('utf-16')`, which will come with a BOM.  If you don't want a BOM, explicitly use either `utf-16le` (little-endian) or `utf-16be` (big-endian).

Comment: I had already tried that but I then get "ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)" however the solution of user711413 worked so problem solved thanks